# Why i am getting this error which tells that method must return a value of type float

Tags: java, compiler-errors, method-call

I was trying to write a code to check the biggest number among the three numbers but by calling a method from another class. This is the code for the method where the numbers are checked . but i am getting this error .

```
package method;

public class Three_Number_Method_Class_Calling {


    public static float biggestNumberOfAll(float a ,float b,float c ) 
    {
        if(a>b) {
            if(a>c) {

                return a;
            }
        }

        else if(b>c) {
            return b;
        }
        else {
            return c;
        }


    }
}
```

Comment: What will your method return when `a>b` and `a<=c`? Your internal `if` does not have its own `else`.

Answer (score 1):

You are getting this error, because you did not specify  what to return if `if condition` fails, it does not know what to return , here is a correction

```
package method;

public class Three_Number_Method_Class_Calling {

    public static float biggestNumberOfAll(float a ,float b,float c ) 
    {
       float max = a;
       if(b > max){
        max = b;
       }
       if(c > max){
        max = c;
       }
       return max;

    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

A non-void method must return a value in every code path. You have a case (when `a > b` and `a <= c`) where you don't return any value:

Lets say `a = 3`, `b = 2` and `c = 5`.

First `if` statement enters its `then` branch: `if (a > b)` (3 is bigger than 2).
The `if` statement inside of that body will not enter its `then` branch: `if(a > c)` (3 is not bigger than 5). At that point, no `else` branches will be executed since you've entered the first `then` branch, method code ends and you don't return anything.

---

In order to fix that, you could remove the last `else`:

```
public static float biggestNumberOfAll(float a, float b, float c) {
    if(a > b) {
        if(a > c) {
            return a;
        }
    }
    else if(b > c) {
        return b;
    }
    return c;
}
```